# Configuration issue with rabbitMQ and sneakers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq, bunny, sneakers

I have two applications sap1 and sap2 and i have been using rabbitMQ (bunny gem) for messaging, so that is working like from sap1 i will create the message and publish

**sap1 (publisher app)**

Gemfile

```
ruby 1.9.3
gem 'bunny', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.1'
```

publish.rb

```
def publish
    # Start a communication session with RabbitMQ
    connection = Bunny.new(:host => "123123", :vhost => "1231", :user => "123", :password => "Z7tN")
    connection.start

    # open a channel
    channel = connection.create_channel

    # declare a queue
    queue  = channel.queue("order-test", :durable => true)

    # publish a message to the default exchange which then gets routed to this queue
    values = { mac_id: 14123 }
    queue.publish(values.to_json)
    connection.close
end
```

**sap2 (consumer app)**

Gemfile

```
ruby 2
gem 'bunny'
gem 'sneakers'
```

config/initializers/sneakers.rb

```
require 'sneakers'
Sneakers.configure :connection => Bunny.new(:host => "123123", :vhost => "1231", :user => "123", :password => "Z7tN"), :timeout_job_after => 360
```

Rakefile

```
require 'sneakers/tasks'
```

app/workers/mac_worker.rb

```
class MacWorker
  include Sneakers::Worker
  from_queue "order-test"

  def work(params)
     # Calling the function
  end
end
```

and in the console for listen doing this

```
 bundle exec rake sneakers:run
```

Here this is working, sometimes i am getting connection issue also, in the consumer app i don't want to use sneakers gem so instead i want to read message from queue with bunny and put it into sidekiq, also how to listen automatically in sidekiq?

Comment: Your issue is your approach to how you are coding.  Your production env shouldn't be different than your development environment.  It's one of the core tenants of 12 factor which is a Rails Way.  You are suffering because you aren't following it.  

You need to get that all installed the same in both, read the sidekiq tutorials to get that working & then come back with the error message (which will be same in prod/env)

Comment: I agree with @Mirv.  If you use RabbitMQ/bunny in production, use it in staging and test and development also.  The way to do this is to create separate queues for each environment.  When your code runs, it should have a different configuration for each environment; that configuration can specify which queues to use.  That way you use the exact same code in every environment.

Comment: oh shit, that was my mistake, i was doing correct in the code, that got change when i wrote here